# AKS service connection with kubeconfig

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-aks

I am trying to create an Azure Service Connection to AKS using a kubeconfig configuration. I would like to use terraform to create this.

I have tried something like below and I am unable to get it working. My goal is that the AzureDevops AKS service connections are automatically created using ONLY terraform

When I try the example below, I get the following error.Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

*Configuration*

```
data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks-read" {
  name                = var.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
}

resource "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_kubernetes" "serviceendpoint_kubernetes" {
  project_id            = data.azuredevops_project.p.id
  service_endpoint_name = var.service_endpoint_name
  apiserver_url         = var.apiserver_url
  authorization_type    = "AzureSubscription"

  kubeconfig {
    kube_config = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks-read.kube_config_raw
  }
}
```

*Error*

```
Stack trace from the terraform-provider-azuredevops_v0.3.0 plugin:

panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

goroutine 31 [running]:
github.com/microsoft/terraform-provider-azuredevops/azuredevops/internal/service/serviceendpoint.expandServiceEndpointKubernetes(0x0?)
        github.com/microsoft/terraform-provider-azuredevops/azuredevops/internal/service/serviceendpoint/resource_serviceendpoint_kubernetes.go:186 +0x128f
github.com/microsoft/terraform-provider-azuredevops/azuredevops/internal/service/serviceendpoint.genServiceEndpointCreateFunc.func1(0x0?, {0x189cc00?, 0xc0004b86c0})
        github.com/microsoft/terraform-provider-azuredevops/azuredevops/internal/service/serviceendpoint/commons.go:167 +0x73
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*Resource).create(0x1b8bda0?, {0x1b8bda0?, 0xc00026fef0?}, 0xd?, {0x189cc00?, 0xc0004b86c0?})
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.23.0/helper/schema/resource.go:695 +0x178
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*Resource).Apply(0xc0003f1ce0, {0x1b8bda0, 0xc00026fef0}, 0xc0004b1790, 0xc000489a80, {0x189cc00, 0xc0004b86c0})
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.23.0/helper/schema/resource.go:837 +0xa7a
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*GRPCProviderServer).ApplyResourceChange(0xc0000d3620, {0x1b8bda0?, 0xc00026fdd0?}, 0xc00026a960)
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.23.0/helper/schema/grpc_provider.go:1021 +0xe3c
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/tf5server.(*server).ApplyResourceChange(0xc000282960, {0x1b8bda0?, 0xc00026ed50?}, 0xc0003b8310)
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.14.0/tfprotov5/tf5server/server.go:818 +0x574
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/internal/tfplugin5._Provider_ApplyResourceChange_Handler({0x19f8c40?, 0xc000282960}, {0x1b8bda0, 0xc00026ed50}, 0xc0003b82a0, 0x0)
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.14.0/tfprotov5/internal/tfplugin5/tfplugin5_grpc.pb.go:385 +0x170
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC(0xc0003dc000, {0x1b8ea40, 0xc000190b60}, 0xc0002f4900, 0xc000424750, 0x20b0620, 0x0)
        google.golang.org/grpc@v1.48.0/server.go:1295 +0xb0b
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0xc0003dc000, {0x1b8ea40, 0xc000190b60}, 0xc0002f4900, 0x0)
        google.golang.org/grpc@v1.48.0/server.go:1636 +0xa1b
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2()
        google.golang.org/grpc@v1.48.0/server.go:932 +0x98
created by google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1
        google.golang.org/grpc@v1.48.0/server.go:930 +0x28a

Error: The terraform-provider-azuredevops_v0.3.0 plugin crashed!

This is always indicative of a bug within the plugin. It would be immensely
helpful if you could report the crash with the plugin's maintainers so that it
can be fixed. The output above should help diagnose the issue.
```

Comment: Is this not possible with the official AzureRM provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, at the end I fixed the issue with the following code. Posting the answer here in case it helps others

```
resource "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_kubernetes" "serviceendpoint_kubernetes" {
  project_id            = data.azuredevops_project.p.id
  service_endpoint_name = "${var.name}-1"
  apiserver_url         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config[0].host
  authorization_type    = "Kubeconfig"

  kubeconfig {
    kube_config = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config_raw
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is unnecessary closing bracket at the end of kube_config line
kube_config = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks-read.kube_config_ra***w)***

There is also no closing bracket for azuredevops_serviceendpoint_kubernetes, but probably this may be copy-paste issue in this case.

Comment: Fixed, these were copy and paste issues since I was trying quite alot of combinations. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The [kube_config_raw](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/kubernetes_cluster#kube_config_raw) attribute is **base64 encoded**. The resource `azuredevops_serviceendpoint_kubernetes` expects it to be in YAML format, therefore you need to add or use the [base64decode](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/base64decode) function in Terraform when referencing the attribute.

Also, the `kube_config_raw` attribute is inside the [kube_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/kubernetes_cluster#kube_config) block, most likely must be referenced like this: `kube_config[0].kube_config_raw`.

Example:

```
resource "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_kubernetes" "serviceendpoint_kubernetes" {
  project_id            = data.azuredevops_project.p.id
  service_endpoint_name = var.service_endpoint_name
  apiserver_url         = var.apiserver_url
  authorization_type    = "AzureSubscription"

  kubeconfig {
    kube_config = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks-read.kube_config[0].kube_config_raw)
  }
```